# How to deal with local/UTC DateTime conversion in Kendo MVC Grid?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, datetime, razor, kendo-grid

I'm getting mad with the Kendo grid. In my ASP.NET MVC project I use a database that contains archive values with a UTC datetime. I want to show these values on my page, but I need the datetime values to be shown as local (browser context) datetime. I also do have two JQuery datepickers for the start/end datetime selection of the desired range that must also work with local time. These two datepickers modify the filters of the grid on each change.

I already managed to change the filter's datetime to UTC by using this code when the datepicker's values change:

```
var filterExists = false;
$.each($filter, function (index, entry) {
    if (entry.field == "DateValue" && entry.operator == "lte") {
        entry.value = EndDate.toISOString();
        filterExists = true;
        console.log("UTCEndDate: " + EndDate.toISOString());
    }
})
if (filterExists == false) {
    $filter.push({ field: "DateValue", operator: "lte", value: EndDate.toISOString() });
}
```

When I look into the POST request, the start and end datetimes get send as UTC.

Now the controller fetches the data from the DB like this:

```
public ActionResult JournalData([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
{
    JsonResult jsonNetResult = new JsonResult { JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
    var JournalData = db.DoubleDataValueArchive.ToDataSourceResult(request, x => new JournalEventModel
    {
        DateValue = x.DateValue,
        StationId = x.StationId,
        Value = x.Value,
    });

    jsonNetResult.Data = JournalData;
    return jsonNetResult;
}
```

Using this code, the data gets returned to the grid in UTC. The data is shown in the grid, but the datetimes don't match the values in the datepickers (which show the local datetime).

As I could not figure out a way to convert these datetimes to local time in the grid itself, I tried converting it to local time in the controller by using

```
DateValue = x.DateValue.ToLocalTime(),
```

in the code shown before. But now the grid's datetime filter values don't match. Now, when I want to show data for e.g. the last two hours, the most recent hour is not shown when the client's time is UTC+1. This is extremely annoying and I don't know how to resolve this issue.

As far as I can see, sending and returning datetimes to and from the server in UTC would be the most stable way. All conversion should be done on client side and not on the server. It seems that the grid can not work with UTC "under the hood" and display local time whereever it gets rendered on the page.

I hope that somebody ran into this issue before. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You're definitely on the right lines saying that the client should perform the transformation. Aside from anything else, `ToLocalTime()` will always use the *server's* time zone. I can't provide any help on the JS front, but making the API between the client and server work solely in UTC sounds right to me.

Comment: Thanks Jon. You're right, ToLocalTime() would have been an ugly workaround as it would silently deliver wrong values when client and server don't use the same timezone. I hope that some Telerik magician shows up soon because I'm on the verge of implementing my own "Kendo-free" solution ;-)

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but check out moment.js.  I did something like this to help getting it into the format I wanted.  columns.Bound(p => p.EstimateDate).ClientTemplate("#= moment(EstimateDate).format('ll') #");

Comment: @Robert did you ever find and answer to this? Having the same problem now :-/

Comment: @Pugz: Yes, I did. I gave up all the annoying Kendo and Telerik stuff completely and switched to my own solutions based on Knockout.js, Moment.js and jQuery. Sounds more complex at first, but in the end I'm way faster and much more flexible now. Now I use UTC everywhere (DB, Web App) and only the clients convert datetimes to their local time.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. Can you point me in the direction of being able to put something like that together?